# shell script to monitor php process

Tags: php, shell, process

How can I auto restart a process when it is dead?

I am currently doing it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;do
    ps -aux 2>/dev/null |grep redis_subscribe|grep -v grep >/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
        php /data/www/wwwroot/app.eclicks.cn/oil/index.php public/redis_subscribe subscribe   2>&1 >>/data/cilogs/manitor/image_upload.log &
    fi;
    sleep 10;
done;
```

Comment: what you mean with dead?

Comment: it is not very clear what you mean here. Try to give more explanation about what you want, what your code is supposed to do and why it is not useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;do
    ps -aux 2>/dev/null |grep redis_subscribe|grep -v grep >/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
        php /data/www/wwwroot/app.eclicks.cn/oil/index.php public/redis_subscribe subscribe   2>&1 >>/data/cilogs/manitor/image_upload.log &
    fi;
    sleep 10;
done;
```

2>/dev/null is to redirect "Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus" to /dev/null

and, >/dev/null is the same.
hope to help you!